# Right URL encoding of query parameters with special characters in PHP

Tags: php, http, url

There are some characters that are not correctly encoded neither by urlencode() or htmlentities() in PHP, since I guess they weren't in the initial set.

For instance, something like http://youtu.be/2MfXW_lUZOc will be encoded as "http%3A%2F%2Fyoutu.be%2F2MfXW lUZOc"(notice the white space replacing the underscore)

I'm looking for something similar to the encodeURIComponent() javascript function. Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure? Work as intended for me, try and paste: `echo urlencode("http://youtu.be/2MfXW_lUZOc");` here: http://writecodeonline.com/php/

Comment: ``urlencode()`` should do the trick... your url encoded with the mentioned php function return http%3A%2F%2Fyoutu.be%2F2MfXW_lUZOc - which is totally right...